# How to Update a Google Sheet directly in R without creating a CSV file in the computer

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, googlesheets4

I am trying to develop a web scraping code. **I need to automate it and run it in the Google Cloud daily**. The daily web scrapped data have to be saved in a Google sheet. Following is the relevant part of the code that I have developed to save data in a CSV file and then upload it to an existing Google Sheet.

```
# Here is a sample data set 
apt_link <- c('https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/6220b265d188d1cf74252fbb',
'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/622f314859ff6df2ed86c2ee',
'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/619ca702f1a2b400224637d4',
'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/61cc1cf099a6ef002161f721',
'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/606761cd2c34720022d4117f')
rooms <- c(4,5,2,4,3)
Surface <-c(87.09,104.00,44.90,138.00,146.00)
cost <- c(389000,497000,279000,1890000,1600000)
address <-c('1140 Wien','1210 Wien','1210 Wien','1180 Wien','1060 Wien')

# Creating a dataframe with web scrapped data
df_one <- cbind.data.frame(apt_link,rooms,surface,cost, address, Sys.time())

# Saving data as a CSV file in the computer
con <- file('Real_Estate_Wien_Data.csv',encoding="UTF-8")
data <- write.csv('Real_Estate_Wien_Data.csv', file=con, row.names = T)

# Write Google sheets
library(googlesheets4)
library(googledrive)
drive_auth()

# Link to the folder in my google drive
td <- drive_get("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ZK6vUGXhRfzCPJ9I-gIrj3Xbzu72R1e3")

# Update
drive_put('Real_Estate_Wien_Data.csv', name = "Real_Estate_Wien_Data", type="spreadsheet", path=as_id(td)) # keeps id because of other links
```

The issue here is that now this code creates a CSV file on my computer. So that when I am going to automate it on the Google Cloud Platform, I think it's not possible to save the CSV file. There has to be another way to directly write the data to a Google Sheet.

Thank you in advance, and your suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **Google Apps Script**, as it is specifically built to interact with **Sheets** and other Google files. It seems to me that you would like to accomplish 3 different tasks, I've summarized them below:

- **Fetching Drive folders and files:** This can be accomplished by Apps Script's [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) class. From here you can fetch folders via `getFolderById()` or `getFoldersByName()`, as well as fetching individual files with the same dynamic.
- **Writing data into spreadsheets**: You can do that using the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class. The are many ways in which a Spreadsheet can be modified via code, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) is a simple example of using the `Range.setValues()` function to write some data in the spreadsheet.
- **Running the code daily:** Within Apps Script, you can easily set up **Triggers** (read more about them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)) that will enable you to automatically run the code daily in the cloud, without interacting in any way with your local computer.

Comment: CastanderThank you for your valuable answer, but I also need to use an R script that will web scrap and create data. So I will have to research more about how to integrate R script with Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found the solution, but you can absolutely use `googlesheet4`package to write your data to a new or existing spreadsheet.  Check out the `write_sheet()` function [here](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/sheet_write.html).